# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TModel' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

I'm trying to publish a MVC4 application into appharbor, copying locally System.Web.MVC but still getting this error.

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the NuGet dll - please make sure you're referencing the NuGet dll and not your local system one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/aspnetmvc

Also check out this support issue: http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1314-error-pushing-mvc4-application

Comment: I rechecked all that but I'm continuing having a problem. Could it be any version incompatibility between the assembly and appharbor stack?